# jQuery get text with $.each from a multiple select list

Tags: jquery, select, iterator

I'm trying to get the text of some selected options from a select list with the jQuery.each function.

I select all selected options like this: `$('#IdOfSelect option:selected')`
This works just fine.

If I iterate over this jQuery-object I always get the error `value.text()` is not a function when I try to get the text of my single option.

You can see this behaviour here: http://jsfiddle.net/z2nbP/

In the Firebug-Console the item shows as `<option value="10">` instead of my expected `[option]` (if it's a DOM-object).

How is it possible to iterate over those selected options and although get there texts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need this:

```
$(value).text()
```

because the `value` parameter passed to the callback is the native DOM element which doesn't have the `.text()` method defined on it.

Here's the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z2nbP/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/9arYE/

Answer (score 0):

value is not a jquery object, you have to make it as a jquery object in this way-

```
$(value).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$('#result').append($(this).val()+'
');